Hilarious show with an old man at hospital because of his heart, his children think he is dying because of his wife
I once watched a hilarious show where in an episode, an old man is at a hospital because of his heart. Everytime his - horrible - wife comes into the room, his heart starts beating wildly. His children think that his wife is stressing him and that's why he had a heart attack. But in the end, he says that his wife makes his heart beats wildly because he loves her.
I can't tell you much about this show. It was broadcast on French TV on Paris Premiere about 15 years ago.
Edit: I watched it in English with French subtitles, so it was British or American.

So was it French?

No, it was British or American, because I watched it in English with French subtitles.
